# Had gone stupid

Tags: word-meaning

M. Puzo, the Godfather:

> What annoyed Clemenza was that the execution had to be "public". That
>   is, the body was to be found. He would have much preffered having it
>   disappear. ([...]) But it had to be public so that *embryo* traitors
>   would be frightened and the enenmy warned that the Corleone Family had
>   by no means gone stupid or soft.

I'm confused by the word embryo and the Corleone Family had by no means gone stupid or soft. Couldn't you explain the meanings here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An "embryo," literally, is a baby in a womb.  So "embryo traitors" is a metaphor meaning "people in the early stages of becoming a traitor" or "people considering betraying the Corleone family."

"gone stupid or soft" is just a slang way of saying "become stupid or soft."  And "soft" in this context means the opposite of "tough."